# Save functions order in phpdoc

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm running `phpdoc` on my project and there's a file (the only meaningful file), in which the order of methods is important for grouping methods.  How can I have the same order of functions in the generated documentation as in the source file?

Actually, I'm ready to change doc framework, if it helps.

Comment: Although this is not a bad question, having to rely on the order of functions/methods is bad practice (at least in PHP).

Comment: @DanFromGermany: Yes, but maybe from a documentation standpoint you want related functions to be grouped together.  Kind of like php.net where array functions are not mixed in with PDO functions etc...

Comment: If you have several groups of functions inside of single php class/file - I'd suggest you to split them into different classes/namespaces

Comment: Ordering is as important as indentation... What you want is to be able to read your code without any extra documentation. Actually, documentation is a bit useless when it comes about code.

Comment: The requirements of the project (something like existing API skeleton) is just plain functions without OOP, so I can't just wrap it into some classes.

Comment: You could wrap it into several files.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear there is a way to tell the documenter what order to list methods in.

However, `@see` may be useful to you to draw attention to the related functions. That coupled with a note in the full description about the order being needed, or some out of order exceptions may be the best the tool can currently offer.

Comment: I like your answer and I'll award it with bounty if no better answers are supplied.

Answer (score 1):

check the below url for steps to document a PHP program,

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.phpdocumentor.intro.php

Comment: This doesn't address the specific question, but is a good reference. He tagged the question with `phpdoc` and mentions it, so I assume he knows the general idea.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is not possible to declare a specific order.

It is possible to build `@package`s tho, which is meant for namespaces in PHP (afaik..).

If you have declared a `@package`, you can define `@subpackage`s to group methods/functions.

```
<?php
namespace Stackexchange\Stackoverflow;
/**
 * My Answer
 * @package Stackexchange\Stackoverflow
 * @see http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.subpackage.pkg.html
 */

class Answer
{
    /**
     * @subpackage SomeSubGroup
     * @return $this
     */
    public function doSomething {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @subpackage SomeOtherSubGroup
     * @return $this
     */
    public function doSomethingDifferent {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Besides the grouping feature, you should try to improve your programing by semantically and logically splitting big classes into smaller, business parts.

Comment: There are valid reasons for wanting to preserve function order that has nothing to do with poor OO practices. Especially in documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the requirements of the project make me using plain style insead of OOP.